# My local site directs to install.php after update from production site af drush sync

Tags: installation, drush

Just set up drush for a site, database and site root set up in MAMP. I've updated the local directory using these drush commands:

```
drush rsync @alias.production @alias.local
drush sql-sync @alias.production @alias.local
```

The terminal doesn't display any errors and I can see in my local phpmyadmin + in the site folder that both files and database entries are synced. Still the local URL directs me to /install.php (also after running `drush cc all`)

I've done this several times before without difficulties. Any ideas how I should debug this behaviour to find my error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Settings.php was there, but thanks to @Peter's answer I took a look at it and discovered that the `$databases = array();` sequence on line 213 wasn't followed by my database login info for some reason. I edited line 213 to the following and it works again:

```
    $databases = array(
  'default' => 
  array (
    'default' => 
    array (
      'database' => 'mydatabasename',
      'username' => 'myusername',
      'password' => 'mypassword.',
      'host' => 'localhost',
      'port' => '',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => '',
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Is settings.php there? It is not synced by default with drush rsync.

The redirect to the install page also indicates that you are missing settings.php.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can also be caused by incorrect permissions or ownership on the files copied by rsync. You might want to do this in your docroot after running `drush rsync`:

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data -R /path/to/www/*
sudo chmod u+r -R /path/to/www/*
sudo chmod u+rw -R /path/to/www/drupal/files/directory
```

... assuming that www-data is your web server user (default under Apache2 on Debian)